# BlackBerry Dynamics - do the Xamarin bindings work with the new Dynamic Framework beta?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-dynamics

I maintain several iOS apps that use BlackBerry Dynamics Bindings for Xamarin.iOS. One of our apps has a production version that was build against version 6.0.1.6 of the bindings, along with an earlier version of the SDK and targeted iOS 12.

With iOS 14 coming out, it is time to rebuild the app, which means it is time to update the SDK, the bindings, and the dlls in my project. When I went to the developer portal, I found the SDK download page now has two options for the "BlackBerry Dynamics SDK for iOS". There is a "Static Framework v8.1.0.37" and a "Dynamic Framework beta v8.1.0.37".

According to the documentation, the dynamic framework, while in beta, does eliminate much of the complicated linking required in previous versions, and does away with the custom LD scripts for FIPS compliance. I would like to try it out, but I could not find an indication anywhere in the documentation files on the developer portal as to whether or not the Xamarin bindings work with this version of the SDK. Do they?

The currently available bindings are version 7.0, which target iOS 13; the iOS 14 readiness blog post says newer bindings are planned for mid-October of 2020. If the current bindings do not work with the dynamic framework sdk, is there any plan to have the next release do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlackBerry Dynamics SDK 8.1.x for Xamarin will not support using the dynamic library found within the BlackBerry Dynamics SDK for iOS.  It currently only supports the static library.  We do plan to add support for the dynamic library to our SDKs for Xamarin, Cordova and React Native in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look forward to the future releases.